# how to change object name into different name when using laravel eloquent relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to change the courses object's name from "courses" to "levels" in the response via the eloquent query or if there's a way to do so. Because I don't have much time to change The whole project since the project is already live but now working on API for a mobile developer and I don't want to be there any confusion with names because of my client made me change many things when I was building the project;

This is my eloquent code:

```
 $languageLevels = Category::with('courses')->get();

  return response()->json(['code'=>1,'success'=>true, 'languageLevels'=>$languageLevels]);
```

The response:

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "success": true,
    "languageLevels": [
        {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "German",
            "status": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-10-10T08:16:21.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-10T18:35:34.000000Z",
            "courses": [
                {
                    "name": "Beginners",
                    "content": "Beginner level",
                    "image_name": "1602175010.jpg",
                    "uuid": "1887da0c-0864-4d8c-9447-e427c06085ae",
                    "status": 0,
                    "category_id": 25,
                    "created_at": "2020-10-08T16:36:50.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-10T15:34:07.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "ُEnglish",
            "status": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-10-08T16:34:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-08T16:34:32.000000Z",
            "courses": [
                {
                    "name": "Intermediate",
                    "content": "Intermediate",
                    "image_name": "1602181221.jpg",
                    "uuid": "2dcb6d86-ded0-4419-bf1a-7c30ecf6f4fb",
                    "status": 1,
                    "category_id": 24,
                    "created_at": "2020-10-08T18:20:21.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-10-08T18:20:21.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is How I want it to be like: from "courses": [ to "levels": [

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "success": true,
    "languageLevels": [
        {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "German",
            "status": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-10-10T08:16:21.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-10T18:35:34.000000Z",
            "levels": [
                {
                    "name": "Beginners",
                    "content": "Beginner level",
                    "image_name": "1602175010.jpg",
                    "uuid": "4444-e427c06085ae",
                    "status": 0,
                    "category_id": 25,
                    "created_at": "2020-10-08T16:36:50.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-10T15:34:07.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "ُEnglish",
            "status": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-10-08T16:34:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-10-08T16:34:32.000000Z",
            "levels": [
                {
                    "name": "Intermediate",
                    "content": "Intermediate",
                    "image_name": "1602181221.jpg",
                    "uuid": "2dcb6d86-ded0-4419-bf1a-7c30ecf6f4fb",
                    "status": 1,
                    "category_id": 24,
                    "created_at": "2020-10-08T18:20:21.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-10-08T18:20:21.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
``
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources. You can structure the response any way needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through each object and assign `courses` object to new key `levels`.
But it will increase the execution time as you need to loop through each result.

Or you can use `map` also.

If speed is not an issue and don't have many records then you can use this approach or as alternative to that you can use eloquent resource as @DigitalDrifter suggest. So you have to change in that resource only instead of all places.

[Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

Answer (score 1):

In the Category model you can just add this.

```
    public function courses(){
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function levels(){
        return $this->courses();
    }
```

The method `levels` is same as `courses`. So you can use anyone of them if needed.

```
    $languageLevels = Category::with('courses')->get();
```

Or

```
    $languageLevels = Category::with('levels')->get();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).